# Not able to identify the iframes using selenium

Tags: java, html, selenium

Trying to find and switch to **iframe** in the page, but it is showing the number of iframe as 0.

The iframe is present in html code.

**Html code:**

```
<iframe id="walkme-native-functions" style="display: none; position: absolute;"></iframe>
<iframe id="walkme-proxy-iframe" src="about:blank" style="display: none; visibility: hidden;"></iframe>
```

**Java code:**

```
 List<WebElement> frames=chromeSelDriver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));
 System.out.println(frames.size());
 System.out.println(frames);
 chromeSelDriver.switchTo().frame(0);
```

**Html code:**

```
<iframe id="walkme-native-functions" style="display: none; position: absolute;"></iframe>
<iframe id="walkme-proxy-iframe" src="about:blank" style="display: none; visibility: hidden;"></iframe>
```

**Output of Java code:**

```
0
[]
```

Comment: Html code:

<iframe id="walkme-native-functions" style="display: none; position: absolute;"></iframe>
<iframe id="walkme-proxy-iframe" src="about:blank" style="display: none; visibility: hidden;"></iframe>

Comment: I think it's because frames are hidden and non-visible. (display: none; visibility: hidden;)

Comment: Or try below code before you find frames:

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.tagName("iframe")));

Comment: Also, there is typo in your code, referring to frame(0) instead of frames(0) you are missing the "s"

Answer (score 0):

Selenium has been written such that it does NOT allow interaction with hidden elements.
The idea behind it is that if a person cannot perform an action, then neither can Selenium.
Since both your iframes are hidden, selenium is unable to recognize these elements.

However, you can use Javascript with Selenium to interact with a hidden element.